# Parse Complex Structure of XML

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to show data before parsing Local XML but don't know how?I tried it by using this

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("People.xml");
var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("array")
       select new Person {
         Name = (string)query.Element("string"),
       };
listBox1.ItemsSource = data;
```

but it shows me only one element.

XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dict>
    <key>Categories</key>
    <array>
        <string>Playing baseball</string>
        <string>Driving a car</string>
        <string>Getting dressed</string>
        <string>Eating a hamburger</string>
        <string>Tying shoelace</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I want to parse all string element.

Comment: Your XML seems to be ill-formed, the opening `<plist>` tag is missing.

Comment: now it's correct please let me know how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You want to iterate the elements within the `array` element, so we call `Descendants("array").Elements()`. There's no need to cast `query.Value` to a string as the `value` property is returned as a string.

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("People.xml");
var data = (from query in loadedData.Descendants("array").Elements() 
            select new Person
            {
                 Name = query.Value,
            }).ToList();
listBox1.ItemsSource = data;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Element(System.Xml.Linq.XName)` method only returns one element--the first child element with the specified name. Use the `Elements(System.Xml.Linq.XName)` overload instead, which returns a collection of all elements whose name is the specified name.

Try this code:

```cs
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("People.xml");

// Get all the <string /> elements from all th
var data = 
    from query in loadedData.Descendants("array") 
    from stringElem in query.Elements("string")
    select new Person { Name = (string)stringElem.Value };

listBox1.ItemsSource = data;
```